# How can I convert a FormData string to a Javascript or JSON object?

Tags: javascript

I have a test I'm trying to write for a request that uses FormData to submit a multipart form. I'm using Nock to try to mock the request

```
    const submit_claim_request = nock(gatewayClient.defaults.baseURL)
      .post('/api/v2/claims', (body) => {
        return (
          JSON.stringify(body) ===               //<-------- this does not work
          {
            default_employee_wallet_id: '0000000046',
            amount: 1,
            category: 'Parking',
            reimbursement_vendor: 'Test vendor',
            transaction_date: '2021-10-03T00:00:00.000Z',
            note: 'test description',
            is_multi_month: false,
            'file[]': file,
          }
        );
      })
      .reply(200, {
        data: {
          reimbursement: {
            amount: '1',
            category: 'Parking',
          },
        },
      });
```

However, I can't figure out how to convert my FormData from my Axios request to a JS object.

This is what my `body` looks like:

```
----------------------------792417295264678490134208
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="default_employee_wallet_id"

5cc7f9432e041785dea91a7a
----------------------------792417295264678490134208
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="amount"

1
----------------------------792417295264678490134208
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="reimbursement_vendor"

Test vendor
----------------------------792417295264678490134208
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="category"

gym_and_fitness
----------------------------792417295264678490134208
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="transaction_date"

2021-10-03T00:00:00.000Z
----------------------------792417295264678490134208
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="is_multi_month"

false
----------------------------792417295264678490134208
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="note"

test description
----------------------------792417295264678490134208
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file[]"; filename="chucknorris1.png"
Content-Type: image/png

(⌐□_□)
----------------------------792417295264678490134208--
```

Answer (score -1):

it seems you are checking that `JSON.stringify(body)` is equal to an object.

Try to `console.log(JSON.stringify(body))` and notice that it would not be equal to the object you are checking it against.

The response received from the `axios` should already be in JSON format if it is returned as a JSON object.

What you would do is now to check for object equality between `body` and the object you expect it to be equal to.

Lodash's [`_.isEqual`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3198202/13944042) method can be good for this.

```js
  const submit_claim_request = nock(gatewayClient.defaults.baseURL)
      .post('/api/v2/claims', (body) => {
        return (
          _.isEqual(body, {
            default_employee_wallet_id: '0000000046',
            amount: 1,
            category: 'Parking',
            reimbursement_vendor: 'Test vendor',
            transaction_date: '2021-10-03T00:00:00.000Z',
            note: 'test description',
            is_multi_month: false,
            'file[]': file,
          })    
        );
      })
      .reply(200, {
        data: {
          reimbursement: {
            amount: '1',
            category: 'Parking',
          },
        },
      });
```

==================

Here is an example of my request:

```
      const form_data = new FormData();
      form_data.append('default_employee_wallet_id', "foobar");
      form_data.append('amount', 12.34);
      ...
      
      receipts.forEach((file) => {
        form_data.append('file[]', file);
      });

      const axios_instance = axios.create()
      axios_instance.post('/api/v2/claims', form_data);
```

Comment: Hi. `body` is the long string i pasted above, so it will fail the equality comparison with an object

Comment: Ahh, I see. I misunderstood how exactly nock worked! I will explore an alternate solution.

Comment: Hello @bigpotato, do you mind uploading a sample http request you are making to the nocked url? I am unable to recreate a scenario where `body` is not an object.

Comment: I updated the question with a simplified example of what my request looks like